# Excel chart - spread different time frames to express as percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to compare revenue per month across construction projects that have different time frames, but want to show the revenue as a percentage of time so that the different time frames are not relevant.
ie project 1 is 6 months and has 6 revenue data entries, project 2 is 12 months and has 12 revenue data entries. I want compare the % revenue at % time on a line chart. I have currently had to manually space out project 1 so that its number of data entries becomes 12 in order to compare the way I want.
Is there a way an excel chart can spread my data entries from 0-100% automatically so that I can compare any data series at any % point in time?

Comment: Hi, please provide a simple test file or some screenshots to better understand this question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, calculating the percentages in a separate column and giving these values to chart should solve your problem (Your question would be clearer if you show/upload a sample data).